# Trouble generating levels in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I currently have run into a wall playing around with Pygame.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random

pygame.init()


#############Constants##############

display_width = 800
display_height = 640
SIZE = (display_width, display_height)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

background = Surface((32,32))
background.convert()
background.fill(Color('#783131'))

x =  0
y = 0
w = 143
h = 170
platx = 600
platy = 500
platw = 50
plath = 50
platformlst = []

obstacle_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
obstacle_y = -500
new_x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
new_y = -500
obstacle_speed = 5
obstacle_w = 50
obstacle_h = 50

level = [
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
    "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                     PPPPPP               P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

collisions = 4

pygame.display.set_caption("My game")

char_img = pygame.image.load("yasuo.png")
obstacle_img = pygame.image.load("poro.png")

obstacle_rect = obstacle_img.get_rect()

char_rect = char_img.get_rect()
print char_rect
print obstacle_rect

#################Objects################


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, player_img):
        self.exists = True
        self.grounded = False
        self.name = "Player 1"
        self.health = 100
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.velx = 0
        self.vely = 0
        self.player_img = player_img
        self.move_speed = 5

    def spawn(self):
        return screen.blit(self.player_img, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    def loseHealth(self, dmg):
        self.health -= dmg
        return self.health

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.velx
        self.y += self.vely
        if not self.grounded:
            self.y += 7
        self.grounded = False

        return self.x, self.y

    def right(self):
        self.velx = 20  

    def left(self):
        self.velx = -20

    def up(self):
        self.vely = -20

    def collide(self, collisions):  
        if (obstacles.exists and 
        obstacles.x < player.x + player.w and
        obstacles.x + obstacles.w > player.x and
        obstacles.y < player.y + player.h and
        obstacles.h + obstacles.y > player.y):
        obstacles.exists = False
            player.loseHealth(25)
            collisions -= 1
            print obstacles.exists

        if (platforms.platx < self.x + self.w and
        platforms.platx + platforms.platw > self.x and
        platforms.platy < self.y + self.h and
        platforms.plath + platforms.platy > self.y):
                print "Player collision"
                self.grounded = True
        return collisions


class Obstacle:
    def __init__(self, obstacle_x, obstacle_y, ob_img):
        self.exists = True
        self.x = obstacle_x
        self.y = obstacle_y
        self.w = obstacle_w
        self.h = obstacle_h
        self.obstacle_img = ob_img
        self.speed = 10
        self.counter = 0

    def spawn(self):
        self.rect = obstacle_img.get_rect()
        if self.exists == True:
            screen.blit(obstacle_img, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
            if self.y > display_height:
                self.y = 0 - self.h
                self.x = random.randrange(0, display_width)
        else:
            self.exists = False

    def move(self, move_speed):
        self.y += (move_speed * self.speed)
        return self.y

    def update(self):
        if not self.exists:
            self.exists = True
        return self.exists

    def collide(self):
        if(platforms.platx < self.x + self.w and
    platforms.platx + platforms.platw > self.x and
    platforms.platy < self.y + self.h and
    platforms.plath + platforms.platy > self.y):
#           print "platform collision"
            self.speed = 0


class Platform:
    def __init__(self, platx, platy, platw, plath):
        self.platx = platx
        self.platy = platy
        self.platw = platw
        self.plath = plath

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [self.platx, self.platy, self.platw, self.plath])


obstacles = Obstacle(obstacle_x, obstacle_y, obstacle_img)
player = Player(x, y, w, h, char_img)

####################Game Loop###################### 

game_exit = False

while not game_exit:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
            print "pressed key"

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print "move left"
                player.left()

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print "move right"
                player.right()

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print "move up"
                player.up()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.velx = 0 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.vely = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print "pressed mouse button"
            player.velx += 20
            player.vely += 20

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            print "mouse button up"
            player.velx = 0
            player.vely = 0 




    platforms = Platform(platx, platy, platw, plath)


    for i in range(32):
        for j in range(32):
            screen.blit(background, (i*32, j*32))

    for i in level:
        for j in i:
            if j == "P":
                platformlst.append(platforms)
                platforms.draw()
                player.collide(collisions)
                obstacles.collide()
            platforms.platx += 32
        platforms.platy += 32
        platforms.platx = 0

    obstacles.spawn()
    player.spawn()
    obstacles.move(1)
    if not obstacles.exists and random.randrange(0, display_width): 
        obstacles = Obstacle(new_x, new_y, obstacle_img)
        obstacles.spawn()
    player.move()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Basically, I am trying to get the list `level` generated onto the screen as `platforms`.  Basically just block that are 32x32 in size. I have parts of the level that are generating but they don't look like they are even in the correct positions to begin with. From what I have been researching, perhaps it is better to do this by putting `level` into a matrix (list of lists)?  Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Can you add your game.py code to the question please?

Comment: @Cplusplusplus sure, I'll add it in for future reference purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug.  `platx` and `platy` both had values that were not equal to 0.  after I made them equal to 0, all worked fine.